# Windows 7 - How to access my documents from Windows 8 (dual boot)

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, multi-boot, windows-8

I am dual booting Windows 7 and Windows 8 on two different partitions of the same drive:

- Win7: (C:)
- Win8: (D:)

I am trying to get access to my Win7 user folder (C:\Users\Mason) in order to access my Win7 documents folder (C:\Users\Mason\Documents) from Windows 8.

When I try to on Windows 8, I get an error message saying "You don't have permission to access this folder. Click here to permanently get access to this folder".

When I click, the progress bar in Windows Explorer slowly moves to the maximum and disappears. When I try opening the folder, I get the same error message.

When editing security permissions for the folder in Windows 8, Explorer freezes.

I do not know how to remove the restrictions from Windows 7. I checked the Windows 8 user folder (D:\Users\Mason) and it had the group or user name: "S-1-5-21-936898901-3363470404-1273668825-1001". I tried copying and pasting it into the Win7 User Folder Permissions, but got the error "An object with the following name cannot be found".

How would I access my folders?

Comment: Use a tool like Total Commander, running as Administrator, to access files on the other partition. Messing with SIDs is pointless, because apart from the built-in accounts, they will be different across installations.

Comment: For some reason, it started working. I'm not sure why.